Redmine-Installation, "bundle exec rake generate_secret_token" ends in "cannot load such file -- manpages (LoadError)"
I set up a brand new Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (several times now)
There is my root-user and there is a lower privileged redmine-user. All basics.
I went straight forward to following the Redmine-Installation guideline on
Redmine Installation Guide
In the past hours I managed to solve every occuring problem. And espeacially with the dependency hell of ruby I got slighdly mad, but I made my way. Sadly, now I got stuck.
Executing bundle exec rake generate_secret_token ends in the error message Error loading RubyGems plugin "/var/lib/gems/3.2.0/plugins/manpages_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- manpages (LoadError)
I changed the ownership of the folders and files. Did not work.
I changed the permissions of folders and files. Did not change a thing.
How can I fix this?
